# How to transfer tables in Outlook 2010 emails to Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have around 2000 emails which were sent to me in a zip file. The emails have the following structure:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/429285

All mails have the same Subject. As can be seen from the screenshot, each mail has multiple tables. These tables have varying number of rows with each mail. My task is to get all of these multiple tables contained in 2000 mails into excel to form graphs and charts. Can you please help me with how to go about this through automation. I tried a few solutions available but found nothing which could transfer tables within Outlook emails to Excel. I have a deadline for this task and any prompt help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What format are the mails? RTF? HTML?

Comment: The mails were directly copied from Outlook. So they are of .msg format.

Comment: I realize they are *.msg files, but what format is the content? Typically if it's not just plain text it's either HTML or rich text format....

Comment: @TimWilliams the auto-generated mail is in HTML format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

Add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` In your VBA project (under *Tools >> References* in the VB editor)

[image]

Assumes outlook is already open, and your mails are stored in the path `MSG_PATH`.

```
Sub Tester()

Const MSG_PATH As String = "C:\_Stuff\test\mails\"

Dim ol, m, t, r, c
Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim rng As Range, rw As Object
Dim f

    Set ol = GetObject(, "outlook.application")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")

    f = Dir(MSG_PATH & "*.msg")

    Do While Len(f) > 0

        Set m = ol.CreateItemFromTemplate(MSG_PATH & f)
        doc.body.innerHTML = m.htmlbody
        m.Close False

        For Each t In doc.getElementsByTagName("table")
            rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = f
            For r = 0 To t.Rows.Length - 1
                Set rw = t.Rows(r)
                For c = 0 To rw.Cells.Length - 1
                    'ignore any problems with merged cells etc
                    On Error Resume Next
                    rng.Offset(r, c).Value = rw.Cells(c).innerText
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Next c
            Next r
            Set rng = rng.Offset(t.Rows.Length + 5)
        Next t

        f = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams! I tried working with the above piece of code. However, I keep getting an error "Compile error: User-defined type not defined". The compiler then highlights the line:
Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
I tried several solutions provided for this type of error like adding references or first defining it as an object. But none of them worked. Could you please tell me where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention you need to add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` In your VBA project (tools >> references in the VB editor)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I really appreciate your prompt reply :)

Comment: @TimWilliams I get an error ActiveX component can't create object (Error 429) when I run this code